# R Parallel processing ending prematurely

Tags: r

I am having an issue with parallel processing and the foreach function in R.  I am registering 6 clusters immediately before running my foreach code and monitoring the progress.  I see intially my CPUs spike to 70% (100% expected since im registering all 6 cores), but after a few seconds it decreases and seems to be finishing the rest of the job on a single core. I have run the same bit of code on my linux machine with the doMC package where I get 100% of cpu for about 10 seconds and then it decreases and finishes on one core. This leads me to believe the problem is how I have written my code.

I have a data set of locations with beginning and end lat/lon columns.  I am using the geophere package to calculate a great cirlce path from beginning to end for each row which expands each original row in the data set to 12 rows after which I am rbinding the results back into a data frame for plotting.

My entire data set should be around 35M rows when complete so I would really like to take advantage of the multiple cores.

```
library(foreach)
library(doParallel)

cl = makeCluster(6)
registerDoParallel(cl) 

arc = foreach (i = temp$id, .combine = rbind, .packages = "geosphere") %dopar% {
    data.frame(
    id = rep(temp[i, 9], 12),
    supplier = rep(temp[i, 1], 12),
    receiving_facility = rep(temp[i, 2], 12),
    commodity = rep(temp[i, 3], 12),
    weight = rep(temp[i, 4], 12),
    time_period = rep(temp[i, 5], 12),
    lat = gcIntermediate(p1 = c(temp$supp_lon[i], temp$supp_lat[i]),
                         p2 = c(temp$rec_lon[i], temp$rec_lat[i]), n = 10,
                         addStartEnd = TRUE)[,2],
    lon = gcIntermediate(p1 = c(temp$supp_lon[i], temp$supp_lat[i]),
                         p2 = c(temp$rec_lon[i], temp$rec_lat[i]), n = 10,
                         addStartEnd = TRUE)[,1])
    }
stopCluster(cl)
```

[image]

Comment: it's probably because we just followed different tutorials but I use `registerDoMC(numberOfCores)` from doMC pakage to register the required number of tutorials. Might possibly help

Comment: doMC doesn't work in Windows, but I used on my linux set up and got the same results

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this would be better as a comment but I do not have the reputation for it yet.

To my understanding, and from my experience, it is working as intended.  Running the code in parallel.  However, the row binding function (i.e. putting it all back together) is done on a single core which is why you see that extra single-core processing time at the end.

Answer (score -1):

Run the process without combining results . Or return a dummy value so that combine is very fast . This way you can confirm if the single core is due to .combine or if it is due to code issue. As far as your code is concerned , it seems okay and the parallelism is implemented as expected.